# Placing people around table

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Find number of ways to place 10 people around circular table, so between two specific persons are exactly other two. For those two specific persons, we have 16 possible combinations, and $8!$ permutation for other 8 people. Is this right? I'm not sure because the table is circular.

Comment: I'll go out on a limb and say I *think* it's $40,320$ ways. There are $C(8,2) = 28$ ways of choosing the two people to sit between the two given people, and once chosen, you can treat the ways of arranging them around the table as $7$ objects arranged around the table (the $4$ people together is one "object", and the remaining $6$ people are the other "objects"), which can be done in $(7-1)! = 6!$ many ways. Finally, the two people between the given two can be seated in two different ways (interchanging them puts different ones next to each of the given two). Thus, $C(8,2)*6!*2 = 40,320.$

Comment: Did you mean to say between two specific persons are exactly two others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a circular arrangement, only the relative order of the people matters.

Suppose the two specific persons are Anne and Barbara.  Seat Anne.  Barbara can either sit three seats to Anne's left or three seats to Anne's right.  That ensures there are exactly two people between Anne and Barbara.  Once Anne and Barbara are both seated, the remaining eight people can be seated in $8!$ ways as we proceed clockwise around the table from Anne.  Hence, there are
$$2 \cdot 8!$$
admissible seating arrangements.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Also, if you were to care about the absolute positions of the people (which is the way in interpreted the question) you would get $10 \cdot 2 \cdot 8!$ arrangements.